# How to insert null in SQL database for using C# object properties of type decimal or string or int

Tags: c#, sql, null

I have Employee class with the below properties

```
       class Employee{

           public int?  EmployeeId {get; set;}
           public string Name{get; set;}
           public decimal? Salary{get; set;}
       }
```

I have created an object

```
Employee emp = new Employee(){EmployeeId = 10, Name = "Peter", Salary = 1000.0}
```

I have written below Insert query inside **LoadEmployee()** method to insert Employee object data into Employee table

```
public static void LoadEmployee(Employee obj){
     string sqlString = @"Insert into dbo.Employee (EmpId, Name, Salary values ('"+ obj.EmployeeId + "','"+ obj.Name +  "','"+obj.Salary"')";
     SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlString, this.sdwDBConnection);
     queryCommand.Executereader();     
}
```

When we have non null values for EmpId, Name or Salary, the code is working fine. The challenge is that Name or Employee Id or Salary can be null. I am able to assign null value to Salary with the below statement.

```
  emp.Salary = null;
  emp.Name = null;
```

After inserting Insert query, when I verify in db, Name is updated with string value "null"  and  Salary is updated as 0. I am expecting null values to be inserted to Name and Salary fields in Employee table.

Please help me how to insert null for Name or Salary in the database in this situation.

Comment: you're building a string, and c# has no idea that's an SQL string. your null is probably becoming a plain-jane-regular empty string. if you want to insert a null that way, you have the embed the literal characters `n`, `u`, `l`,`l` into the query string.

Answer (score 6):

Use parameters. You have to explicitly replace `null` with `DBNull.Value`:

```
string sqlString = @"insert into dbo.Employee (EmpId, Name, Salary) values (@empId, @name, @salary)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString, this.sdwDBConnection);
command.Parameters.Add("@empId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = obj.EmployeeId;
command.Parameters.Add("@salary", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = (object)obj.Salary ?? DBNull.Value;
...
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Never concatenate strings to create a query. It makes you vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Also, your `queryCommand` is not query, it's a command. So you shouldn't name it 'query', and you should use `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute it.

Comment: Thank you Jakub for the reply.